# Inequality involving 1-norm, discrete Wasserstein distance and majorization

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, vectors, normed-spaces, optimal-transport

For $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^d$, we say $x\succeq y$ if

$$\sum_{i=1}^j x_i\geq\sum_{i=1}^j y_i \text{ for all }1\leq j< d,\text{ and }\sum_{i=1}^d x_i=\sum_{i=1}^d y_i.$$

If $x\succeq y$, define
$$\mathcal{T}(x,y):=\sum_{i=1}^d i(y_i-x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^d\sum_{i=1}^j(x_i-y_j).$$
Showing the two expressions are the same is not bad.

**Claim:** $$\lVert x-y\rVert_1\leq\mathcal{T}(x,y),$$
where $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$ is the Taxicab norm.

One proof (found in the paper "[The Pasulsen Problem Made Simple](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.04726)" by Hamilton and Moitra) shows that $\mathcal{T}$ is equivalent to the Wasserstein distance on the real line using its dual version. Then the inequality becomes a comparison of costs of moving piles in different ways.

**Is there a more elementary way to prove this?** I only need the result for nonnegative vectors $x$ and $y$, i.e., all their coordinates are nonnegative.

Comment: Hi, I think after the definition of \mathcal{T} you switched  and .

Comment: No, I copied that line from the paper from p. 5. Under the assumption $x\succeq y$, the two definitions of $\mathcal{T}$ are equal!

Comment: Ah, I also misread $y_j$ for $y_i$! Still, this identity is not obvious to me... If you have verified it, I'd be curious to see the proof :)

Comment: \begin{align*}
    \mathcal{T}(x,y)&:=\sum_{j=1}^d j(y_j-x_j)\\
    &=(y_1-x_1)+2(y_2-x_2)+\cdots+d(y_d-x_d)\\
    &=y_1+2y_2+\cdots+dy_d-(x_1+2x_2+\cdots+dx_d)\\
    &=(x_1-y_1)+2y_1+2y_2+\cdots+dy_d-(2x_1+2x_2+\cdots+dx_d)\\
    &=(x_1-y_1)+((x_1-y_1)+(x_2-y_2))+3y_1+3y_2+3y_3\cdots+dy_d-(3x_1+3x_2+3x_3+\cdots+dx_d)\\
    &=(x_1-y_1)+((x_1-y_1)+(x_2-y_2))+((x_1-y_1)+(x_2-y_2)+(x_3-y_3))\\
    &\ +4y_1+4y_2+4y_3+4y_4\cdots+dy_d-(4x_1+4x_2+4x_3+4x_4+\cdots+dx_d)\\
    &\quad \vdots
\end{align*}

Comment: \begin{align*}
    &=(x_1-y_1)+((x_1-y_1)+(x_2-y_2))+\cdots+((x_1-y_1)+(x_2-y_2)+\cdots+(x_{d}-y_{d}))+\\
    &\ +(d+1)y_1+(d+1)y_2+\cdots+(d+1)y_d-((d+1)x_1+(d+1)x_2+\cdots+(d+1)x_d)\\
    &=\sum_{j=1}^d\sum_{i=1}^j(x_i-y_j)
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows since $(d+1)\sum_{i=1}^d x_i=(d+1)\sum_{i=1}^d y_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much!